# internet explorer cannot render https S3 files

Tags: internet-explorer, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have static files hosted in AWS S3 that I serve on a web page.  They use https and look like:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/com-mml-test/static/app/images/food1-full.jpg
```

They render in all browsers except for internet explorer (11).

When I change the above to use http they render no problem:

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/com-mml-test/static/app/images/food1-full.jpg
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

How can I render the https version of the images in internet explorer?

Comment: Do you see any warnings regarding mixed content (or anything similar) in your console output? You can press F12 to check your console; you'll likely want to refresh the page with the developer tools opened.

Comment: @Sampson I added the real image above.  Nothing shows in the console output.

Comment: What can you tell us about the page you're attempting to load this image into? Is it HTTP, or HTTPS?

Comment: @Sampson its an http page. but click on the image above in internet explorer, it gives you a page not found.

Comment: Your screenshot suggests IE 9, yet you mention IE 11. Which version of IE are you testing, and on which operating system?

Comment: @Sampson I've tried on both 9 and 11 with same result.  Does the https version of the url above render for you?

Comment: [check your IE security settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/28516280). Also, the [snipping tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snipping_Tool) makes screenshots so you don't have to literally take a picture of the screen.

Comment: @tedder42 will I tell each person to check their security settings?  I'm testing on several machines and this one will not render images.